# Conversion of html object to string failed using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, type-conversion

Tried to convert my parsed html object to string but it returned only the title. Would appreciate some input in this regard

```js
var html = `<html><title>My title</title><head></head><body><h1>hello World</h1></body></html>`;
html = $.parseHTML(html);
//do something here
//after parse to object, revert back to string
htmlString = $(html).prop('outerHTML'); //this is not working

console.log(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why not append to body?

Comment: Do you want all the characters except the HTML tags?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I want to original string like it's first declared

Comment: @guradio that's not what I want, I have to do something else..

Comment: Like you want the initial var html thing again? It doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator it make sense, I did not write full code, I parse the html string to object to do some manipulation, after that I want to parse it back to string.

Comment: why do you need the html,head and body tag, this looks more like a xy question

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var _html = `<html><title>My title</title><head></head><body><h1>hello World</h1></body></html>`;
_html = $(_html);
htmlString = $('<div></div>').append(_html).html() ; //this should work

console.log(htmlString)
```

;

Comment: you don't skip the parsing

Comment: uh? select twice??

Comment: oops! I forgot, there are html tags in it. Incorrect answer for this

Comment: this will give you `<title>My title</title><h1>hello World</h1>` still skipping `body` and `html` tags

Comment: I want the full html string like before

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new element, then append the html to it and finally print the html of the new element.

Try this:

```js
var html = `<html><head><title>My title</title></head><body><h1>hello World</h1></body></html>`;

var fake_html = $( document.createElement('html'));
fake_html.html(html);

//As jQuery object, you can do whatever you want with this fake_html (here I just change the Title string)
fake_html.find('title').html("Title changed");

htmlString = fake_html.prop('outerHTML');

console.log(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have a string of html. I convert it to append some more element. I want to convert back to string to store it somewhere. How does your fake html approach helps?

Comment: Check the update. If you want the full html as string, you can create a new 'html' element, set his html value with the string, do whatever you want with it and finally get his outerHTML.